# CakePHP 3 - Allowing the user to assign and change an order to a query of records

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Currently in my system, via CakePHP 3, a query to a MySQL database is made searching for a list of photos that are used in a [slideshow plugin](http://www.jquery-backstretch.com/). The user chooses which photos to be used in the slideshow and can add or remove photos from the slideshow. However, they cannot currently choose the order the slideshow displays those photos.

In the Controller, the query looks like this:

```
$imagesUsed = $this->Gallery->find('all',[
    'conditions' => ['status' => 'shown', 'type' => 'image']
])->toArray();
```

On the page to display the slideshow:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            $('#header').backstretch([
                <?php foreach ($imagesUsed as $image){ ?>
                "<?= $host.$basepath ?>/webroot/uploads/<?= $image->link ?>",
                <?php } ?>
            ], {duration: 2000, fade: 750});
        });
    });
</script>
```

I was wondering how to assign numbers to the queried slideshow photos to display the order clearly to the user, and also allow them to change that order. For example:

- A slideshow for fruits currently has an Apple image (1) and a Banana image (2).
- The user then wants to upload a Peach image for the slideshow, but does not want it added as the 3rd image, instead they want to change Peach to be the first image. They do not want to have to remove all images from the slideshow and then re-add the images in the correct order.

**Update:** I've added a custom_sort column in the DB table. I've also made a form with a foreach loop, and a dropdown select that includes a JavaScript onchange function upon an option being selected. I'm struggling to figure out a way to join the two together.

**Form with Foreach loop (incomplete):**

```
<?php $this->Form->create($gallery) ?>
<legend><?= __('Update Image Order') ?></legend>
<fieldset>
    <div class="container col-sm-12">
        <?php foreach ($galleries as $gallery): ?>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <?php echo $this->Form->input('link',['class' => 'form-control', 'readonly']); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <?php echo $this->Form->input('name',['class' => 'form-control', 'readonly']); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <?php echo $this->Form->input('page', ['class' => 'form-control', 'readonly']); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <?php echo $this->Form->input('custom_sort', ['label' => 'Slideshow Order', 'class' => 'form-control']); ?>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </div>
</fieldset>
<div style="text-align: center">
    <?php echo $this->Form->button(__('Submit'), ['class' => 'btn btn-secondary btn-xl page-scroll']) ?>
</div>
<?php $this->Form->end() ?>
```

And in the controller:

```
public function updateorder()
{
    $galleries = $this->Galleries->find('all',[
        'conditions' => ['status' => 'shown', 'type' => 'image'],
        'order' => ['custom_sort' => 'ASC']
    ])->toArray();

    if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
        $galleries = $this->Galleries->patchEntities($galleries, $this->request->data);
        if ($this->Galleries->updateAll([$galleries], [])) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The image slideshow orders have been updated.'));

            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'managemedia']);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The image slideshow orders could not be updated. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
    $this->set(compact('galleries'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['galleries']);
}
```

**Dropdown Select and JavaScript onchange function (incomplete):**

```
<label for="page" id="pageLabel" style="text-align: left">Page</label>
<select name="page" id="page" onchange="changePage()" class="form-control">
    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Select a page</option>
    <option value="Home">Home</option>
    <option value="Fruits">Fruits</option>
    <option value="Vegetables">Vegetables</option>
</select>

<script>
function changePage() {
    var pageChoice = document.getElementById('page');
    var selectedPageChoice = pageChoice.options[pageChoice.selectedIndex].value;
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?= $host . $basepath ?>/gallery.json",
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (res) {
            console.log(res);
        }
    })
}
</script>
```

`console.log(res)` shows me this in the browser console:

```
> Object
  > galleries: Array (x) //galleries being the array variable set in the AJAX request URL, Array (x) referring to the number of elements in that array.
    > 0: {id: 1, link: "images/apples.jpg", name: "Apple", page: "Fruits", custom_sort: 1}
    > 1: {id: 2, link: "images/banana.jpg", name: "Banana", page: "Fruits", custom_sort: 2}
    > 2: {id: 3, link: "images/pumpkin.jpg", name: "Pumpkin", page: "Vegetables", custom_sort: 1}
    > 3: {id: 4, link: "images/peach.jpg", name: "Peach", page: "Fruits", custom_sort: 3}
```

I can retrieve a single value from this like so:

`console.log(res.galleries.0.link);` would print Peach in the console.

Currently the form shows 4 duplicates of form inputs (equal to the number of existing entries), though they're all blank.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery UI Sortable (http://jqueryui.com/sortable/). You can serialize your sorting order on release and update your database with an AJAX-request.

Comment: Not exactly what I'm after - it's more of a: I can enter a new number for Item 3 to make it Item 1. All the images are displayed in a table, not a HTML list like the demo - as there are multiple slideshow reels, each with their own sequences, dragging table rows would be very confusing.

Comment: To clarify, I mean that the user selects the images for specific slideshows from a table that shows all images.

Answer (score 0):

I usually add a column called sortable or custom_sort in the db.

You can give the user an input to specify their own order.

Your query would look like this.

```
// Notice I call Galleries. This may not be right for you, 
// but cake convention is plural table names
// I also use where() instead of conditions. This is also a suggestion
$images = $this->Galleries->find('all')
    ->where(['status' => 'shown', 'type' => 'image'])
    ->order(['custom_sort' => 'ASC']);
```

I would also suggest instead of calling toArray yourself just set the serialize variable

```
$this->set(['images' => $images]);
$this->set('_serialize', 'images');
```

And make sure your request expects json

```
$.ajax({dataType:'json'});
```

**Submitting the Updated Order**

When updating the images you can do a mass update assuming your posted data looks like this.

```
$requestData = [
    [
        'id' => 100,
        'custom_sort' => 1,
    ],
    [
        'id' => 200,
        'custom_sort' => 2,
    ],
    [
        'id' => 300,
        'custom_sort' => 3,
    ]
];
```

You can save the data quickly like this

```
$galleries = $this->Galleries->newEntities($requestData);
// This does not call callbacks (beforeSave, afterSave)
$this->Galleries->updateAll($galleries);
```

**Edit based on Question**

Updating multiple records might look something like this.

In your output loop through your images

```
<?php foreach($images as $image): ?>
    <input data-image_id="<?= $image->id; ?>" class="image-custom-sort" value="<?= $image->custom_sort; ?>" />
<?php endforeach; ?>
<button onClick="handleSubmit">Save Sort Order</button>
```

Then some javascript. It has been a while since I have written Jquery so some of the jquery specific pieces might be wrong but this should give you an idea. Don't copy and paste this code below as I don't think it will work as is.

```
function handleSubmit(e){
    var inputs = $('input.image-custom-sort');
    var data = [];
    $.each(inputs, function (input) {
        data.push({
            id: input.dataset.image_id
            custom_sort: $(input).val()
        })
    });

    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        data: data
    })
}
```

Comment: How would the form look like for a multiple data update? Would I need to use a foreach statement? I've never really done a multiple data update before, so this is all rather new to me. Additionally, I have an extra dropdown that toggles which records show (eg. choosing Fruits on the dropdown would toggle all the Fruit images only). I was thinking of using a JS onchange function, and then use an AJAX request to pull the appropriate data from the DB, but again, am unsure how to get multiple records and their values out of the success callback (I can get one).

Comment: @mistaq - I have updated my answer with a possible solution.